# Python Imaging Library- trouble with altering the alpha value

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make a number of white pixels transparent, however I'm doing something wrong.

I can alter the colour of the pixels, however my code seems to ignore any alterations I make to the alpha value. I'm fairly new to PIL, and Python in general, so it's probably a relatively simple mistake.

Here's the code:

```
image_two = Image.open ("image_two.bmp")
image_two = image_two.convert ("RGBA")

pixels = image_two.load()

for y in xrange (image_two.size[1]):
    for x in xrange (image_two.size[0]):
        if pixels[x, y] == (0, 0, 0, 255):
            pixels[x, y] = (0, 0, 0, 255)
        else:
            pixels[x, y] = (255, 255, 255, 0)

image_two.save("image_two")
```

Comment: In that last line, `image` should be `image_two`, yes?

Comment: Yep, you're right, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version of PIL does not support alpha channel in BMP files.  I was able to use your code to load a PNG file with alpha.  When I try to write that back out to a BMP file, I get a python exception that tells me "IOError: cannot write mode RGBA as BMP".

Your code says:

```
    if pixels[x, y] == (0, 0, 0, 255):  #black with alpha of 255
        pixels[x, y] = (0, 0, 0, 255)   #black with alpha of 255
    else:
        pixels[x, y] = (255, 255, 255, 0) #white with alpha of 255
```

A white pixel would have the r,g, and b set to "255".  So probably what you want to do is something like this:

```
if pixels[x,y] == (255,255,255,255):
    pixels[x,y] = (pixels[x,y][0], pixels[x,y][1], pixels[x,y][2], 0)  #just set this pixel's alpha channel to 0
```

You may not need an else here, because if the pixels are not white with alpha of 255, you probably don't want to touch them.

I modified your code like this:

```
import Image

image_two = Image.open ("image_two.png")
image_two = image_two.convert ("RGBA")

pixels = image_two.load()

for y in xrange (image_two.size[1]):
    for x in xrange (image_two.size[0]):
        if pixels[x, y][3] == 255:
            pixels[x, y] = (255, 0, 0, 255)
        else:
            pixels[x, y] = (255, 255, 255, 255)

image_two.save("image_two2.png")
```

This code takes my image and writes out a mask - a white pixel where the alpha is 0 and a red pixel where the alpha is 255.

Comment: I'm still having issues with the alpha value- I must be doing something wrong. I tried to use the following code to adjust the alphachannels-                                                            if pixels[x,y] == (255,255,255,255):
    pixels[x,y][3] = 0  #just set this pixel's alpha channel to 0     However I was met with the following error- TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment. As of yet I haven't been able to adjust the alpha, it remains at 255, I assume I'm doing something wrong. What specifically are you using in the above code to adjust the alpha?

Comment: I edited my code above. It creates a complete new tuple using the first 3 components of the old tuple plus 0 for the alpha component.

Comment: just discovered that PIL doesn't recognise BMP's as having an alpha channel, so that's the reason why nothing's been working! Is it possible to delete the white pixels? Or will I have to figure out how to convert the BMP within PIL? I imagine the first option would be easier, however I'm unfamiliar with the syntax to do so. Thanks for all of your help so far!

Comment: If you know you want to remove all the white pixels (by remove I guess you mean set the alpha to zero), then you could do something like `if pixels[x,y]==(255,255,255,255) pixels[x,y]==(255,255,255,0)`.  You'll probably have to save the image out in a different format like png which has alpha support in PIL.

Comment: Ok, so I'm still stuck, however you helped me realise my mistake; that BMP's do not have an alpha value. At the current stage, I have to use a BMP, and therefore need to used an alternative route. Thanks for all of your help though, very much appreciated!

Comment: To be clear, the BMP format does have an alpha channel.  It just isn't well supported by some tools.  Image Magick can work with them.